# Need clarification regarding MVC design pattern

Tags: ios, design-patterns, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I have a reusable UIView with its own .xib file. This UIView would be added to different UIViewControllers as subviews. In the MVC design pattern, my reusable UIView should contain only code for the user interface(UILabels, UIButons, etc..). What I'm confused about is setting up the UILabels and UIButtons. Is the ViewController that contains my UIView responsible for setting up my UIView's UIButton click events and what my UILabel displays? The problem I'm having now is that I have multiple UIViewControllers that reuse the same UIView, but they all implement the same code that sets up my UIView. This end up with lots of duplicate code across my UIViewControllers. If I move the setup code to my UIView to reduce the duplicate code, doesn't that violate the MVC design pattern? Is there a way to create a "Controller" thats only responsible for setting up my UIView so I could reuse my UIView and Controller inside my UIViewControllers?

Comment: This question is not about Swift...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that by setup you mean instructing the UIView on how to draw itself based on some object, this is exactly what the drawRect method is for. UIView also provides an initWithFrame method and you can even create your own initializer if you want. One more option is to create a function in your UIView subclass that will take what ever info you are displaying and will setup the view way you want. Something like: `setupCustomViewWithMyObject(object)`.

All this to say that your setup code should be in your UIView subclass and you are not violating anything.

Comment: By setup, I also mean addiing button actions(have my button push a new screen on my navigation controller). I thought about it, and I think the best way is to have a child UIViewController that add my reusable UIView to it, then add that child UIViewController to my parent UIViewController as a subview. That way, I could add as many child UIViewControllers as I want to parent UIViewControllers without having duplicate code. Is my thinking correct?

Comment: I would keep the IBActions in the UIView subclass as well... The way to think about it in my opinion is that the class `customView:UIView` is already the controller of the xib. You should then implement a delegate pattern to change the target off the action (i.e. a different controller each time). In other word the xib is the view!

Comment: Yes, My IBActions are in my UIView subclass. I agree with using the delegate pattern to delegate the button actions to my UIViewController. But if I have 2 very similar UIViewControllers(they share the exact same UIView subclass and have the exact button actions) wouldn't it be better to just have the UIViewController that implemented the delagate method be a child of another UIViewController to avoid having duplicate code?

Comment: But then you still need to write the code initiating your phantom viewController twice!